# Using variable string in typing in Typescript

Tags: typescript, pick

I need a function, that alters a specific variable in my Object:

```
function updateField(fieldname, newValue){
  return {...this.oldObject, fieldname: newValue};
}
```

And I want to make it Typesafe. Type of fieldName is `typeof clazz`, but what is the Type of `newValue`?
I know Typescripts `Pick`, so full typing would be something like:

```
updateField(fieldname: typeof Clazz, newValue: Pick<Clazz, fieldname>): Clazz
```

but I don't know how to go with non-constant strings. Is that even possible in TS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict a filed name to be a valid object key using `keyof` operator. To get a type of value you can use [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) type `T[K]` where `T` is the object type and `K` is the key type:

```
const foo = {
    a: 1,
    b: 'some string'
};

function update<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K, value: T[K]): T {
    return {
        ...obj,
        [key]: value,
    }
}

update(foo, 'a', 2); // OK
update(foo, 'b', 2); // Error: Argument of type '2' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
update(foo, 'c', 2); // Error: Argument of type '"c"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "b"'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=15&ssc=105&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeAoG2YEMBcMAjADRY4BGhA5BCALYCmM0ATgJZgDm1GAvgG4MGOAFcwwKO3AxRABwAmuKIwA8AFRIwA0jEYAPFWAUQYAa0YBPEHBjqAfAAoQFAFaFN5q4W1aAbrgANqKMHgDa2gC6AJQe6OTYrIxQoqxg8TiZMAB0uS6uZFk4YRaWkYQBwYyFOHz8wvJKKo4IIFrUuNRaAEzRAjAA9AMwAPLaGI3KjC2I7RRdML39QzAAoqysIKyEAIKsXKJMYLA2MFCWcszU3dQw7KZgILC4EBDsXGC4FIHMUEhyuFYuCYKlYMFO50uMFoUA43F4k2arXawAWS0Gw3Wm22MD2ByOJ1skKuACJgCTbvcYI9nq93p9vr9-oDgclGGCIRdSbgSTAAD4wEkUClAA)

Comment: That's perfectly what I needed. Just hoped i can do that with Pick, instead typing around.

Comment: `Pick` would create a "object type" with a key and value (e.g. `{ a: string }`) but what you're looking for is key type and value type separated